# Selenium web driver - Can't find form field

Tags: javascript, html, forms, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Trying to open a web page and fill out a form.  I am able to successfully open the parent form and authenticate and click on the form that I want to fill out.

Once on this form, I try to select the field (`PF_5`) and Eclipse tells me the element is not visible.

The relevant code for the website is here.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <title>RV Roster Form Version 205.0</title>
        <style id="DateInputStyle" type="text/css"></style>
    </head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/PresentationServer/Content/css/Common.css?4.5.3.5" />
    <body>
        <div id="pf_form" class="pf_formcontainer">
            <form id="PF_1" class="form  formBoxShadow" style="height:1600px;width:1800px;display:none;behavior: url('http://app.perfectforms.com/pie.htc');">
                <div Id="PF_4Container" class="PageContainer" class="PageContainer" style="left:0px;top:0px;z-index:0;position:absolute">
                    <div tabindex="" title="" id="PF_4" name="PF_4" class=" page " style="width:1800px;height:1600px;background-color:#ffffff;">
                        <input id="PF_5" name="PF_5" type="text" MaxLength="99" value="" class=" textinput " onclick="return false;"
```

I see where PF_5 is the field I want to select, so I use my code to wait and select it:

```
WebDriverWait wait = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30));
WebElement input =
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("PF_5")));
```

If I try to send keys to it, I get the error that the element is not visible.

When testing it, the browser tab is in the foreground, as expected, but I'm not 100% certain that the browser tab is the one being searched for the element.

Sorry to be so obtuse, but I'm at a dead end and need some guidance.

The form is publicly accessible at this link:

http://app.perfectforms.com/PresentationServer/Form.aspx/Play/FdjigAcE?f=FdjigAcE

Comment: Instead of `presenceOfElementLocated` have you tried `visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("PF_5")`? Elements can be present before they are visible.

Comment: Yes, sir, I have.  Still receiving the same error.

Comment: What version of selenium are you using, and what browser are you trying to test?

Comment: I'm using Chrome and authoring the code through Eclipse/Java.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code, and the error that you are getting, I was able to load the form and enter text using the exact code you posted.

Comment: The relevant line of code would be 
driver.findElement(By.id("PF_5")).sendKeys("SSSS");

Comment: Are you using Java EE as well?  If not, let me know what you're using because it obviously works :)

Comment: Okay, to clarify, I'm using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers (Oxygen Release 4.7.0) and the attendant selenium jar addons 3.4.0

Comment: Latest testing shows that I can find and populate the field from a script if I call the webpage directly.  When I login to the webpage first, it cannot find the field.  Although the new tab is in focus, does the script see the tab or do I have to switch to it programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it seems the script wasn't seeing the new tab even though it was in the front when the script was being run.  I had to use the code below to switch:'

```
String oldTab = driver.getWindowHandle();
        driver.switchTo().frame("MTAzNzg1");
        driver.findElement(By.id("PF_51")).click();

         ArrayList<String> newTab = new ArrayList<String>
 (driver.getWindowHandles());
            newTab.remove(oldTab);
            // change focus to new tab
            driver.switchTo().window(newTab.get(0));
```

Thanks to everyone that helped me find this!